# Stuck on Oracle output

Tags: sql, oracle

Question:

Display last_name, salary and job for all employees who earn more than all lowest paid employees per department outside the US locations.
Exclude President and Vice Presidents from this query. (Use subquery / join)

I am unsure how to structure this properly using the subquery properly

this is what i have tried:

```
SELECT last_name, salary, job_id
FROM employees join locations
USING(department_id)
WHERE job_id <> ANY (SELECT *  
                    FROM employees
                    WHERE job_id <> 'AD_PRES' OR job_id <> 'AD_VP')
AND salary > 
                    (SELECT MIN(salary)
                    FROM employees
                    WHERE country_id <> 'US');
```

Any help on how to structure this properly is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: DEPARTMENTS table and EMPLOYEES table are only 2 with department_id

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT last_name,
       salary,
       job_id
FROM   (
  SELECT last_name,
         salary,
         job_id,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY e.department_id ORDER BY salary ) AS rnk
  FROM   employees e
         INNER JOIN
         departments d
         ON ( d.department_id = e.department_id )
         INNER JOIN
         locations l
         ON ( d.location_id = l.location_id )
  WHERE  e.job_id NOT IN ( 'AD_PRES', 'AD_VP' )
  AND    l.country_id <> 'US'
)
WHERE rnk > 1;
```

**Output**:

```
LAST_NAME                     SALARY JOB_ID   
------------------------- ---------- ----------
Hartstein                      13000 MK_MAN     
Banda                           6200 SA_REP     
Johnson                         6200 SA_REP     
Ande                            6400 SA_REP     
Lee                             6800 SA_REP     
Sewall                          7000 SA_REP     
Tuvault                         7000 SA_REP     
Marvins                         7200 SA_REP     
Bates                           7300 SA_REP     
Smith                           7400 SA_REP     
Cambrault                       7500 SA_REP     
Doran                           7500 SA_REP     
Smith                           8000 SA_REP     
Olsen                           8000 SA_REP     
Livingston                      8400 SA_REP     
Taylor                          8600 SA_REP     
Hutton                          8800 SA_REP     
Hall                            9000 SA_REP     
McEwen                          9000 SA_REP     
Sully                           9500 SA_REP     
Bernstein                       9500 SA_REP     
Greene                          9500 SA_REP     
Fox                             9600 SA_REP     
Bloom                          10000 SA_REP     
Tucker                         10000 SA_REP     
King                           10000 SA_REP     
Zlotkey                        10500 SA_MAN     
Vishney                        10500 SA_REP     
Cambrault                      11000 SA_MAN     
Abel                           11000 SA_REP     
Ozer                           11500 SA_REP     
Errazuriz                      12000 SA_MAN     
Partners                       13500 SA_MAN     
Russell                        14000 SA_MAN
```

**Query 2 - Without using analytic functions**:

```
SELECT last_name,
       salary,
       job_id
FROM   employees e
       INNER JOIN
       departments d
       ON ( d.department_id = e.department_id )
       INNER JOIN
       locations l
       ON ( d.location_id = l.location_id )
WHERE  e.job_id NOT IN ( 'AD_PRES', 'AD_VP' )
AND    l.country_id <> 'US'
AND    e.salary > ANY( SELECT salary
                       FROM   employees ee
                       WHERE  ee.department_id = e.department_id );
```

or

```
AND    e.salary > ( SELECT MIN( salary )
                    FROM   employees ee
                    WHERE  ee.department_id = e.department_id );
```

Comment: ORA-00904: "L"."DEPARTMENT_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 12 Column: 15

Comment: That works. Can you explain what Rank() does as well as PARTITION BY? THANKS

Comment: i thought you would have to use MIN(salary) as a test value

Comment: [`RANK`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) calculates the rank of a value in a group of values - in this case the minimum value(s) has rank 1 and higher values will have higher ranks. `PARTITION BY` determines the groups you are ranking by - so in this case you are finding the salary values ranked in each department.

Comment: You could do it using `MIN()` but then you would need to use a correlated sub-query which would scan the table a second time and be less efficient. Using the `RANK()` analytical function is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    last_name, salary, job_id
FROM employees a
INNER JOIN locations b ON a.department_id = b.department_id
WHERE a.job_id NOT IN (
    SELECT job_id
    FROM employees
    WHERE 
        ( job_id <> 'AD_PRES' OR job_id <> 'AD_VP' ) AND
        salary > (
            SELECT MIN(salary)
            FROM employees
            WHERE country_id <> 'US'
        )
);
```

Works?

Comment: ORA-00904: "B"."DEPARTMENT_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 45

Comment: ah LOCATIONS table does not have department_id attribute

Comment: locations only has the info for the country name